# Are "Christ" and "Son of God" two things or one in John 20:31?

Tags: greek, john, jesus, new-testament, authorial-intent

[John 20:30-31](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2020:30-31&version=NASB) says the following:

> Therefore many other signs Jesus also performed in the presence of the disciples, which are not written in this book; but these have been written so that you may believe that **Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God**; and that believing you may have life in His name.

My question is about the Greek syntax in the phrase highlighted above. Here it is:

> Ἰησοῦς ἐστιν ὁ Χριστὸς ὁ Υἱὸς τοῦ Θεοῦ

Judging by the English alone I can see two distinct possibilities:

- John wrote so that his readers would believe that Jesus is (A) the Christ, and (B) the Son of God (i.e. two distinct identifiers), or
- John wrote so that his readers would believe that Jesus is the Christ / Son of God (presenting the two as synonymous)

Which is it?

Comment: Possibly related: Matt. 26:63, Luke 4:41, John 11:27

Answer (score 7):

When comparing [John 20:30-31](http://www.esvbible.org/John+20:30-31) to other early Christian texts, it appears 'Christ' and 'son of God' (and 'Lord') were understood as synonyms when used for Jesus. The two terms appear in conjunction somewhat regularly<sup>1</sup>, a few you have already noted in a comment above.

The reason for why the two phrases are so often used in relation to each other probably derives from [Psalm 2](http://www.esvbible.org/Psalm+2), which is applied to Jesus in a few New Testament texts.<sup>2</sup> This psalm speaks of someone as both the 'anointed' (Hebrew *messiah*, Greek *christ*) and the 'son' of God.

Psalm 2 was widely regarded as having been written by David (e.g. [Acts 4:25](http://www.esvbible.org/Acts+4:25)). The obvious usage of the Hebrew scriptures in the New Testament and the frequent claims that Jesus is a royal descendant of David reinforce the synonymous meaning of the two titles 'Christ' and 'son of God' in [John 20:30-31](http://www.esvbible.org/John+20:30-31). Psalm 2 uses the two concepts for one person, the (Davidic) king of Israel.

**The son of God = the Christ = the king of Israel** in John 20:30-31.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sub>1. [Matthew 16:16](http://www.esvbible.org/Mattew+16:16); [26:63](http://www.esvbible.org/Matthew+26:63); [Mark 1:1](http://www.esvbible.org/Mark+1:1) (though 'son of God' is regarded as a later addition to this verse); [Luke 4:41](http://www.esvbible.org/Luke+4:41); [John 11:27](http://www.esvbible.org/John+11:27); [Romans 1:4](http://www.esvbible.org/Romans+1:4); [First Corinthians 1:9](http://www.esvbible.org/First+Corinthians+1:9); [Second Corinthians 1:19](http://www.esvbible.org/Second+Corinthians+1:19); [Galatians 2:20](http://www.esvbible.org/Galatians+2:20); [Ephesians 4:13](http://www.esvbible.org/Ephesians+4:13); [Hebrews 5:5](http://www.esvbible.org/Hebrews+5:5).</sub>

<sub>2. Direct quotations in [Acts 4:25-28](http://www.esvbible.org/Acts+4:25-28) and [13:30-33](http://www.esvbible.org/Acts+13:30-33); subtle allusions in [Revelation 2:27](http://www.esvbible.org/Revelation+2:27), [12:5](http://www.esvbible.org/Revelation+12:5), and [19:11-21](http://www.esvbible.org/Revelation+19:11-21).</sub>

<sub>3. Other uses of the two titles in the New Testament texts probably all carry the same meaning, but they would all need to be determined on a case-by-case basis.</sub>

Comment: (+1) Great question and great answer. The answer could be greatly improved by showing that the Greek supports this answer as well, which I believe it does (but am not an authority).